# remove EventListener from treejs AnimationMixer

Tags: three.js

I have an AnimationMixer and I wanted to attach some logic to the end of the animation.
As the documentation instructs - I used addEventListener on the mixer, and it worked fine,
BUT when I tried to remove the listener it didn't work.
(I also tried to see if hasEventListener works, but no luck.)

In short-
The log for addEventListener is working
but removeEventListener and hasEventListener do not.
What am I missing? I could not find any explanations for this.
Would appreciate any help...

```
            this.animationMixer = new THREE.AnimationMixer(gltf.scene);

            this.animationMixer.hasEventListener('finished', (e) => {
              console.log('hasEvent', e); // doesn't print
            });

            this.animationMixer.addEventListener('finished', (e) => {
              console.log('done'); // prints
              this.animationMixer.removeEventListener('finished', (e) => {
                console.log('removed'); // doesn't print
              });
            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[RemoveEventListener() accepts a second argument](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/core/EventDispatcher.removeEventListener) to know which event to remove, but that function doesn’t get triggered on removal. Plus, it should be the same function each time, not a new one:

```js
function hasFinished() {
    console.log(“Finished”);
}

let value = this.animationMixer.hasEventListener('finished', hasFinished);
console.log(value); // false

// Add event listener
this.animationMixer.addEventListener('finished', hasFinished);

value = this.animationMixer.hasEventListener('finished', hasFinished);
console.log(value); // true

// Remove listener
this.animationMixer.removeEventListener('finished', hasFinished);
```

Now the function will get triggered when the “finished” event occurs on its own. It won’t get triggered on adding or removing the event listener.

Comment: The documentation explicitly states that there are 2 arguments and that the other is a function. If I do not specify one I get an error "Expected 2 arguments, but got 1, an argument for 'listener' was not provided."
It even says "listener - The function that gets called when the event is fired." for hasEventListener...
So this is just another case of "don't trust the documentation"?

Comment: @Shaked Yes, I apologize. I edited my answer. You need to use the same function on the add/remove event listener. And then the function won’t get called when you add it or remove it. It will only get called when the animation finishes playing.

Answer (score 0):

I just used  delete this.mixer._listeners and it works. This just deletes the properties from mixer

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).